# Converting coordinates in metres to Longitude & Latitude (CRS conversion) in OGC WKT format?

Tags: coordinate-system, polygon, coordinates, well-known-text, ogc

I have two tools that produce output in OGC WKT format. But they look different. Could you please explain this(I am very new to GIS).

For my project I want the coordinates in the second format. Is it possible to convert from first format to second?

---

Tool 1:
http://dev.giscloud.com/examples/drawingtools.html

POLYGON ((16136169.435794141 -4553684.305378843,16136205.862815436 -4553671.31705568,16136219.448302884 -4553708.341241255,16136182.424117308 -4553720.433817994,16136169.435794141 -4553684.305378843))

---

Tool 2:
https://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html

POLYGON((144.95369132692065 -37.81764246645652,144.9540426963016 -37.81754923679548,144.9541714423343 -37.81782468772676,144.95381470853533 -37.8179263924262,144.95369132692065 -37.81764246645652))

Comment: That's the same format, i.e. `POLYGON ((cood pair, coord pair, etc...))`. What you are seeing is the coordinates output in different coordinate reference systems  (CRS). The top coords look like metres in a projected CRS and the lower ones are Longitude and Latitude in a geographic CRS.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is it possible to convert from the first one above to second one ?

Comment: Please rewrite the question to focus on this new topic.

Comment: Yes, it's possible @Hydrogirl, please edit your question to specify the software you use and what CRS each output is in.

Comment: updated. I am working on a project (customising GISCloud https://www.giscloud.com/) that I have to add a feature to draw a polygon and get the coordinates. So I can use only tool 1 which is their function. But I need the output as Longitude and Latitude.

Comment: Is the polygon in the 'first tool' supposed to be the same polygon as in the 'second tool'? Or do they represent different places? If different places, do you know what location the first polygon represents? Otherwise, we can't identify what the CRS could be.

Comment: @mkennedy: yes, they are the same.

Comment: It's EPSG::3857 AKA "Web Mercator".

Comment: Thanks @mkennedy. It was helpful when using the library as there I had to provide the projection.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the answer with **proj4js** library
http://proj4js.org/

```
var proj4 = require('proj4');

var firstProjection = 'EPSG:3857'
var cod = proj4(firstProjection).inverse([16136169.435794141, -4553684.305378843]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(cod));
```